# Add OpenMesh face only if does not result in complex face/edge/vertex

Tags: c++, openmesh

Is there a way to test whether adding a new face would result in complex edges/faces and skip adding if it would?

The function `add_face` uses 3 ordered `VertexHandle` to add a face to the mesh. If the order of vertices is incompatible with the existing mesh (so that the face would be wrongly oriented) or a triangle already exists with those 3 vertices, this is the typical warning OpenMesh gives:

`PolyMeshT::add_face: complex edge`

I was wondering if it is possible to test whether a face addition would result in such `complex edge` warning and skip the addition if it would? I'm thinking some kind of `try-catch` block. Alternatively, how can I remove the face that caused such an incompatibility?

Note that here my aim is **not** to properly orient the new face. I simply do not want to add it if it causes incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0):

As per  [the nice explanation of the developers](https://lists.rwth-aachen.de/hyperkitty/list/openmesh@lists.rwth-aachen.de/thread/AAI7DZQTLYPUPWKLWLCOENQGXUNW27PM/),

> if you add a face and get this warning, the face will not be actually
> added to the mesh. You will receive an invalid face handle as the return
> value of the add_face function. Therefore you do not have to remove
> anything.